# Printing variable in PHP cause server to return false

Tags: php, variables, memory, printing, echo

I have 145064642 chars long HTML String which I am trying to print.

When I try echo/var_dump/die on it it cause page to return false(0), but if i try to print only half of the variable it is working fine.

EXAMPLES:

Don't work:

`echo $MY_HTML_STR;`
`die($MY_HTML_STR);`
`var_dump($MY_HTML_STR)`

Each of the two line works:

`die(var_dump(substr($MY_HTML_STR,strlen($MY_HTML_STR)/2)));`

`die(var_dump(substr($MY_HTML_STR,0,strlen($MY_HTML_STR)/2)));`

But when trying to print the both together:

```
var_dump(substr($MY_HTML_STR,strlen($MY_HTML_STR)/2));
die(var_dump(substr($MY_HTML_STR,0,strlen($MY_HTML_STR)/2)));
```

it is crashing again.

One way of echoing did gave me an error:

```
echo <<<EOF
    TEXTTEXT...
       $MY_HTML_STR                   
    BLABLAHTML...
EOF;
```

the error: `Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 324009984) (tried to allocate 145090561 bytes) in .....page.php on line 675`

Line 675 is the `EOF;` line.
The script is running on my home computer using WAMPSERVER and memory_limit set as -1 (UNLIMITED).

Comment: This is probably not directly related to your issue, but `var_dump()` does not return anything. Running `die(var_dump(...))` will be similar to running `die(null)` or `die(0)` which of course, exits with code `0`. Same with `echo`. `echo(var_dump(...))` will print `null` after `var_dump()` runs.

Comment: How much RAM does your system have? What other programs are running that are using up your RAM? (The OS, The browser, your FTP program, your text / html editor...)

Comment: WRONG..
http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php

and even if was true, `echo $MY_HTML_STR` causes the same error..

Comment: @TecBrat I have 2.5GB real RAM and 1.5GB Virtual RAM so system can run till reaching 4GB.
But I followed the httpd.exe process and it is not passing the 1GB and the total used RAM is not passing the 2.25GB..

Comment: @eranj, you can see in the manual page you just linked to, at the "Return Values" section, that "no value is returned". That means it doesn't return anything. Again, this is probably not directly related to your issue, I was just pointing out that you should not call `echo(var_dump(...))` or `die(var_dump(...))`, but rather just `var_dump(...)`.

Comment: @Radu there is no use for `echo var_dump()` thats true, but `die(var_dump(...))` is ok, it is var_dumping and than killing the script..

Comment: @eranj, true, that's a useful shorthand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if output buffering is on. Remember that if output buffering is enabled, everything you output will be held in memory until output is flushed (which also happens implicitly on script shutdown).

Try an ob_end_clean() before you print and see if that resolves your issue.

Also, try adding the code below before you print. You could be in nested output buffering (if, for example, you have it enabled in php.ini and you call ob_start at the beginning of your script)

```
print ob_get_level();
exit;
```

Comment: ob_get_level() return true (1);
combining the `ob_end_clean()` and loop of substr() as suggested @Michael Dibbets at his answer solved the problem. THANK YOU !

Answer (score 1):

echo doesnt like too long strings. if you want to print use a for loop to split it in smaller strings with substr() of about 10000 chars or smaller if that gives problems.

You are exceeding the internal write buffer with way too much.

Comment: Is this `echo` limitation documented?

Comment: I read it in the user comments with echo php docs. I ran into a similar issue once and that reseolved my problem. You could compare it to trying to cram 2000 print jobs in a printer at ince, the printer will fail, orthe spool server on your computer.